# Use "X" to close userform and maximize Excel window

Tags: excel, vba, userform

On a worksheet there's a command button to show UserForm1 and also minimize the Excel application's window.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Application.WindowState = xlMinimized
UserForm1.Show vbModeless

End Sub
```

There's code for UserForm1's "X" that unloads UserForm1 and should maximize the Excel window as the front window.

```
Private Sub cmdExit_Click()
If ExitAsk = vbYes Then
    Unload Me
    Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
End If
End Sub
```

Everything works but Excel stays minimized.

Comment: You unload the object before it gets to the windowstate, quick fix: maximize excel before you unload the object that's going to call it, as a general advice: be careful on the life cycle for the code and the objects on it.

Comment: I tried switching the order of unload and maximize to no effect. Excel is still minimized.

Comment: Hmm it could be that the maximize doesn't work inside the userform: try to define within a standard module a sub that does maximize it, and call it before the unload happens, let us know if that work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There's code for UserForm1's "X" that unloads UserForm1 and should maximize the Excel window as the front window.

Is this what you are trying? This will maximize the userform the moment you press the `X` on the userform.

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
End Sub
```

You can also use the `UserForm_Terminate` event for this

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, both code blocks have the intended behavior.